# Replace postal abbreviations with long version

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that has over 4000 addresses and I need to replace postal abbreviations with the long versions. For example, replace Dr with Drive, Rd with Road, etc.

I want to avoid changing words that have the abbreviations in them. For example, when replacing St with Street, I want to avoid changing **St**ar Avenue to **Street**ar Avenue.

Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, but. Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This isn't trivial because of the insane variety of abbreviations and possible locations in the address, aside from the issue you identified of being parts of other words (and the requirements would further vary by country).  It could be done in Excel, but that wouldn't be the ideal software in which to do it.  This would basically require an application, not a few formulas or lines of code.  Way beyond what could be addressed in any reasonable way in a question here.

Comment: Try to include a few examples of addresses, so we can see what your data looks like.